# HTML CSS3 / Canvas Image Distortion

Tags: html, css, canvas, distortion

Is there a way to skew/distort only one corner using CSS3 or canvas tag in HTML5?

Here is a screenshot from Photoshop tutorial how to do it:

[image: Skew in Photoshop]

**Update:**

This is the best I have found so far, but it is not 100% accurate:
https://github.com/edankwan/PerspectiveTransform.js

**Update2:**

I need html5 version of this:
http://www.rubenswieringa.com/code/as3/flex/DistortImage/

Comment: +1 I think it's a pretty interesting question :) I find some info (you probably find it before, but in case of help) about [do it with Kinetics.js](http://codeslashslashcomment.com/2012/12/12/dynamic-image-distortion-html5-canvas/).

Answer (score 2):

This should help you .
[Link1](http://www.subshell.com/en/subshell/blog/image-manipulation-html5-canvas102.html)

And you should try searching before posting a question. I searched for **html5 canvas skew image** and it showed me so many results .

---

**Update**
Check Out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fQk4h/)

```
// Find each img, and replace it with a canvas
$('img').each(function (index, el) {
var c,      // new canvas which will replace this img element
    ctx,    // context of new canvas
    i,      // loop counter
    tmpCtx, // temp context for doing work
    h,      // height of the image / new canvas
    w,      // width of the image / new canvas
    dh,     // destination height (used in translation)
    dw,     // destination width (used in translation)
    dy,     // destination y
    leftTop,// left top corner position
    leftBot;// left bottom corner position

// Get the height/width of the image
h = el.height;
w = el.width;

// Create the canvas and context that will replace the image
c = $("<canvas height='" + h + "' width='" + w + "'><\/canvas>");
ctx = c.get(0).getContext('2d');

// Create a temporary work area
tmpCtx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');

// Draw the image on the temp work area
for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
    dw = Math.abs((w * (h - i) + w * i) / h);
    tmpCtx.drawImage(el,
        0, i, w, 1,   // sx, sy, sw, sh
        0, i, dw, 1); // dx, dy, dw, dh
}

// Calculate the left corners to be 20% of the height
leftTop = parseInt(h * .2, 10);
leftBot = parseInt(h * 1, 10) - leftTop;

ctx.save();

// Draw the image on our real canvas
for (i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    dy = (leftTop * (w - i)) / w;
    dh = (leftBot * (w - i) + h * i) / w;
    ctx.drawImage(tmpCtx.canvas,
        i, 0, 1, h,
        i, dy, 1, dh);
}

ctx.restore();

// Replace the image with the canvas version
$(el).replaceWith(c);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for links, but those links are not helping me. As you see all examples are "normal" skew tutorials like doing this: http://pe-images.s3.amazonaws.com/basics/free-transform/distort-side.gif

or playing with perspective:
http://pe-images.s3.amazonaws.com/basics/free-transform/perspective-top-left.gif

I need to be able to skew only one corner

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/canvas/perspective.html) is what you are looking for.